# How to fix the location of tables when they're imported with \input?

Tags: floats, positioning, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I'm using MiKTeX and TexMaker 2.2.2. Using the latabstat command in Stata I create small tex files of some tables.

They look like:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\begin{tabular}
(table content)
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I compile my main document

```
\begin{document}
\input{tablefromstata}
\end{document}
```

The tables float around - and I want to fix them.

Since the files contain the table command, putting table outside (in the main document), like

```
\begin{table}
\input{tablefromstata}
\end{table}
```

gives error messages.

I tried the floating option `[H]` after the input string 
`input{}[h]` but it seems not to work on `input{}`.
Does anybody know how I can determine the exact location of tables imported using `\input`?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Problem solved. Anyone with the same problem, just type [h] after the caption command in stata.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) The `\input` command simply inserts the content of the external file at this position, nothing more. Do you have a `table` inside or around the `\input`? Please consider to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: For the positing part of the question see [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned). Please tell us if this helps, so we can close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The main document looks like \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

Comment: You can update the question if you want to add new information.

Comment: Apart from the answers in the linked question in Martin's comment, can the `latabstat` command in Stata create a table *not* wrapped in a `tabular` environment?  If so, you can insert the tables exactly where you want them, since they won't float at all.

Comment: Unfortunately not - then I guess I have to delete them by hand.

Comment: @Petter: Please don't add the solution to your question, but add it as an answer. Self-answering is explicitly encouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Use the float package, and change the [htbp] to [H]
Then the tables will not float at all (unless they fall at the bottom of the page, in which case they will have to go to the top of the next page).